# Replacing Punctuation in List of Files

Tags: python, string, file, pathlib

I am trying to replace a '. ' with a '_' for all files in a directory.  The files look like this:

```
000. utm_homescreen.bak
000. utm_homescreen.yxwz
001. utm_chain_screen.bak
001. utm_chain_screen.yxwz
...
```

Right now I am trying to apply a split and join to every file in the directory,  but I don't see these changes reflected in the file names.

```
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path('..').glob('*'):
    if not file.is_dir():
        '_'.join(file.name.split('. '))
```

Comment: look at `Path.rename`, right now you're just making a `str` and not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Path.rename() like this:

```
for file in Path('..').glob('*'):
    if not file.is_dir():
        file.rename('_'.join(str(file).split('. ')))
```

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use the rename function? i didn't runned but should look like this

changed like Mario Ishac suggested

```
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path('..').glob('*'):
    if not file.is_dir():
        Path(file.name).rename('_'.join(file.name.split('. ')))
```

Comment: Should probably use `Path.rename` since `pathlib` is being used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.rename()` and `replace()`:

```
from os, glob
for file in glob.glob('*'): # list of all files in the folder
    if not file.is_dir():
        os.rename(file,file.replace('. ','_')) # rename the file with '. ' replaced with '_'
```